# BASH variables aren't loading properly on startup

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, bashrc

I rarely post a question because I tend to get obsessed with trying to figure things out on my own, but today I am really stuck.... and I've had a long week and my brain is dead...

anyways, I am trying to load a var that draws a horizontal straight line the length of my console.

I've tried drawing the line a couple of ways:

The '⎼' is not an underscore, the char sits a little higher than the underscore ie: ⎼_

1. printf '⎼%.s' $(seq 1 $COLUMNS)
2. python3 -c "print('⎼' * $COLUMNS)"

both commands draws the line, and when I assign it to a var like:
HORZLINE=$(printf '⎼%.s' $(seq 1 $COLUMNS)

and then call $HORZLINE, it also draws the line.

I run into problems when I try to add that line (*HORZLINE=$(printf '⎼%.s' $(seq 1 $COLUMNS)*) to .bashrc and try to load it on start up.

The var loads, but the whole line doesn't load. Only one char is loaded. So when I try:

$: echo -e "$HORZLINE"
⎼

AFTER the terminal boots, if I source the .bashrc file again, the variable loads properly and draws the whole line.

Anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong, or what is going on?

**

### UPDATE - SOLVED

**

I just wanted to give you guys a heads up and update this for anyone out there experiencing the same problem..

All I had to do to fix the problem was to enable force_color_prompt (uncomment it in .bashrc)

Here's a screen shot of my prompt not loading correctly:
[image: force_color_prompt commented out]

and here is what it is supposed to look like:
[image: force_color_prompt enabled]

I feel so stupid. I spent so long trying all these different things, when I should have just looked at the bashrc.

But just so you know, I didn't even think about the force_color_prompt because the terminal was doing some wierd things, like:
1. if I launched mate-terminal, the prompt loaded correctly
2. I re-launch xterm, and NOTHING
3. Messed around with the preferences in xterm, changed the font, launch the terminal again, and it stopped working. BUT if I changed the font back to systems default, it would work again.

So I was messing around with xterm's setting, which if you've had experience with, isn't so easy.

Anyways.. thats it.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the bash man page for COLUMNS,
`Automatically set if the checkwinsize option is enabled or in an interactive shell upon receipt of a SIGWINCH.`
So the key is "interactive shell".  At a terminal type:
printf '⎼%.s' $(seq 1 $COLUMNS)
You get the line.

Put that command into a file (myline), set the executable bit and try:
./myline
Single char output.

bash myline
Single char output

bash -i myline
You get the line again with the explicit "-i" to force an interactive shell.

Comment: checkwinsize IS enabled in .bashrc and calling "$-" gives me: "himBH"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that even when `checkwinsize` is set, the `$COLUMNS` variable doesn't get set until a `SIGWINCH` signal is received.

I'm not sure if it's the *right* way to do it, but this seems to work for me:

```
kill -s SIGWINCH $$
HORZLINE=$(printf '⎼%.s' $(seq 1 $COLUMNS))
echo "$HORZLINE"
```

[EDIT: you don't need `-e` since there are no escape sequences in the string.]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly solve your problem but in my `~/.bashrc` I print a horizontal line in between each command:

[image: terminal dividing line.png]

This is accomplished by setting `$PS1` in `~/.bashrc`:

```
Divider=""
for ((i=0; i<$COLUMNS; i++)) ; do
    Divider="$Divider""─"
done

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${Divider}\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${Divider}\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi

unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Note: if you change the width of the `gnome-terminal` windows you need to resource `.bashrc` with the command `. ~/.bashrc` to get the dividing line resized in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

like I added to my question, the issue was because I didn't have force_color_prompt enabled in .bashrc.

once I uncommented the line, the variables loaded properly.